# Flask Threading requests

Tags: python, flask, server

I Read the flask documents and there was an option like below

> app.run(host="10.343.34534.34543", port=6846,threaded=True)

What does threaded = true mean?

EDIT : This question is Moot , I just didnt know much at the time of asking,

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/serving/#werkzeug.serving.run_simple)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flask.Flask.run` accepts keyword arguments eg. `threaded=True` that it forwards to `werkzeug.serving.run_simple` two of those arguments are: threaded which enables threading, and processes, which you can set to have Werkzeug spawn more than one process to handle requests. So if you do:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(threaded=True)
# Alternately
# app.run(processes=3)
```

Flask will tell Werkzeug to use threading and to spawn three processes to handle incoming requests.

All of that being said, a WSGI like Gunicorn should be used in a production environment. Not Werkzeug.